# Sed with angle brackets

Tags: sed, regular-expression

This works

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]*<default>false/XXX/'
```

Why does prepending a `>` make it fail

```
sed 's/>[[:space:]]*<default>false/XXX/'
```

escaping the `>` does not help either. In other scenarios `>` seems to work just fine. Why not here?

text: `<key type="b" name="launcher-minimize-window">
      <default>false</default>`

Comment: Does your text actually contain a newline? `sed` is line-oriented, so unless you're appending lines to the pattern or hold space, the trailing `>` from the previous line is not in the pattern space to be matched.

Comment: By "fail" you don't mean that `sed` throws an error but that `sed` doesn't match?

Comment: @HaukeLaging doesn't match

Comment: @glennjackman I thought newline is part of [[:space:]]

Comment: @glennjackman yes it contains a newline there

Comment: It is, but sed reads it's input one line at a time, so unless you're doing some programming to accumulate the lines, there won't be any newlines to match. See also https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Examples

Comment: btw I want to do in-place-modificatin of a file

Answer (score 1):

As you already informed by [glenn jackman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4667/glenn-jackman) in comments:

> **sed** reads it's input one line at a time, so unless you're doing some
>   programming to accumulate the lines, there won't be any newlines to
>   match

You are able to push GNU **sed** to treat all file as single line with `-z` option

> -**z**, --**null-data**
>
> ```
>       separate lines by NUL characters
> ```

So you can try

```
sed -z 's/>[[:space:]]*<default>false/XXX/'
```